# Selenium: How use FieldDecorator and Locator.ElementHandler with ArrayList?

Tags: java, selenium, reflection, cglib

I have some complex object on a Page and I would like become it from a simple WebElement from Selenium on one better abstraction:

```
public class MyPage {  

    @FindBy(css="select#testme")  
    public MograblogSelect select;  

    public void changeToOption2(){  
        select.val( "option2" );  
    }  

    public void changeToOption1(){  
        select.val( "option1 ");  

    }  
}
```

This works like a charm following the post: http://www.mograblog.com/2013/08/extending-selenium-in-java.html

But I don't know how to adapt the FieldDecorator and Locator.ElementHandler for be able they work with an ArrayList:

```
public class MyPage {  

    @FindBy(css="select#testmelist")  
    public List<MograblogSelect> selects;  

}
```

In this second case `selects.get(0) always returns null`. How should I do this?

Comment: How is going? If my answer was helpful -- please check a tick near my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your CSS selector is wrong. You can try the following:

```
public class MyPage {  

    @FindBy(css="select#testme>option")
    public List<MograblogSelect> selects;  

}
```

Comment: This returns me null. I tried: `@FindBy(css="select#testme") public MograblogSelect select;  // Returns a MongrabSelect correctly.`, ``    @FindBy(css="select#testme>option") public List<MograblogSelect> selects;  // Returns and empty list.`,`@FindBy(css="select#testme>") public List<WebElement> selects;  // Returns and a list with one item (first @FindBy).`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class MyPage 
{  
    @FindBy(css="select#testmelist")  
    public List<WebElement> selects;  
}
```

And convert it to `MograblogSelect` later, if you wish. The type of the list has to be `WebElement` for the annotation to work.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc clearly mentions **`To mark a field on a Page Object to indicate that lookup should use a series of @FindBy tags It will then search for all elements that match any of the FindBy criteria`**

So your code can be :

```
public class MyPage {  

    @FindAll({@FindBy(css="select#testmelist")}) 
    public List<MograblogSelect> selects;  

}
```